# Upload File from cordova App to Struts2 Service

Tags: android, ios, cordova, struts2

good day, to the point, I'm developing an app with cordova and I am having problems uploading, they do not achieve it work.

i search in the net triying to find the problem but i can no figure it out, when the cordova app call the service in (struts2 service) always the file is null and crash the service.

here is the cordova app code:

```
enviarLogs: function(archivo, url){
    log.info("inicio-fileManager.enviarArchivo");

    //obtenemos el archivo que deseamos enviar
    log.logFolder.getFile(archivo,{create: false, exclusive:false},
        function logCapturado(adjunto){
            log.info("fileManager.enviarArchivo: archivo encontrado, preparando envio");
            //notificaciones.alertar("Salida URI: "+encodeURI(adjunto.fullPath));
            //notificaciones.alertar("Salida URI: "+encodeURI(adjunto.toURL()));
            //var location = "/data/data/ve.com.megasoft.MobilePOS/files/logs/MobilePOSLOGS2015-01-26.txt";

            //opciones del archivo
            var fileOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
            fileOptions.fileKey ="myFile";
            fileOptions.fileName = archivo;
            fileOptions.mimeType = "text/plain";
            //fileOptions.chunkedMode = false;
            //fileOptions.headers = {
                //Connection: "close"
            //};

            //identificacion de procedencia del archivo
            var info = new Object();
            info.value1 = "test";
            info.value2 = "Case";
            fileOptions.params = info;

            //realizamos el envio del archivo
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(
                //location,
                adjunto.toURL(),
                encodeURI(url),
                fileManager.success,
                fileManager.fail, 
                fileOptions,
                true
            );
        },
        function logNoCapturado(error){
            log.error("fileManager.enviarArchivo: Archivo no encontrado, cancelando envio");
            notificaciones.alertar(
                "no se encuentra el log solicitado, no se realizara el envio de informacion",
                undefined,
                "Error"
            );
        }
    );

    log.info("fin-fileManager.enviarArchivo");
}
```

And here is the action in struts2 service:

```
package ve.com.megasoft;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.IOException; 

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class UploadFile extends ActionSupport{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private File myFile;
private String myFileContentType;
private String myFileFileName;
private String destPath;

public String execute() {
  /* Copy file to a safe location */
  destPath = "C:\\test";

  try{
     System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
     System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);

     File destFile  = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
     FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);

  }catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     return ERROR;
  }

  return SUCCESS;
}
   public File getMyFile() {
      return myFile;
   }
   public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
      this.myFile = myFile;
   }
   public String getMyFileContentType() {
      return myFileContentType;
   }
   public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
      this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
   }
   public String getMyFileFileName() {
      return myFileFileName;
   }
   public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
      this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
   }

}
```

advance thanks for the help and hope that you can help me.

edit: added the package:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
<!--         tipos de resultados -->
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
            <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
        </result-types>

<!--         interceptores -->
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="json">
                    <param name="enableSMD">true</param>

                 </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="">
            <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
       <action name="strutsAction" class="ve.com.megasoft.StrutsAction">
          <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
          <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
          <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/success.jsp</result>          
       </action>

<!--        <action name="upload" class="ve.com.megasoft.UploadFile"> -->
<!--           <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/success.jsp</result> -->
<!--           <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</result> -->
<!--       </action> -->
        <action name="upload" class="ve.com.megasoft.UploadFile">
            <result type="json" >
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            </result>
       </action>
    </package>
```

EDIT2: update with the console params extracte from struts2 App

```
Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir
param: value1 Value: test
param: value2 Value: Case
ParamMap: {value1=[Ljava.lang.String;@527b280, value2=[Ljava.lang.String;@6bbe9081}
Attributo: __cleanup_recursion_counter Value: null
Attributo: struts.actionMapping Value: null
Attributo: struts.valueStack Value: null
content Length: 24514
content type: multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++
Src File name: null
```

the output get from ddms

```
upload file:///data/data/ve.com.megasoft.MobilePOS/files/logs/MobilePOSLOGS2015-01-26.txt to http://192.168.1.130:8080/LearnCodeStruct2/upload
fileKey: myFile
fileName: MobilePOSLOGS2015-01-26.txt
mimeType: multipart/form-data
params: {"value1":"test","value2":"Case"}
trustEveryone: true
chunkedMode: false
headers: {"Connection":"close"}
objectId: 3
httpMethod: POST
Content Length: 24514
Sent 24514 of 24514


<html>
<head>
    <title>Struts Problem Report</title>
    <style>
        pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Struts Problem Report</h2>
    <p>
    Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
    </p>


<div id="exception-info">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Messages</strong>:</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>


<div id="stacktraces">
<hr />
<h3>Stacktraces</h3>
<div class="stacktrace" style="padding-left: 0em">
    <strong>java.lang.NullPointerException</strong>
    <div>
    <pre>
    java.io.File.&lt;init&gt;(Unknown Source)
    ve.com.megasoft.UploadFile.execute(UploadFile.java:67)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor.intercept(JSONInterceptor.java:172)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    </pre>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<hr />
<p>
You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled.  Development mode, or devMode, enables extra
debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers.  To disable this mode, set:
<pre>
  struts.devMode=false
</pre>
in your <code>WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties</code> file.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine. Please post the interceptor stack configuration for this action, or this package, because it could be missing the FileUpload interceptor, or containing a restricted list of mimetypes allowed, or size limits, or the interceptor itself could be placed in a wrong position in the stack.

Comment: And this `System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);` is actually printing `"Src File name: null"` ?

Comment: And it seems you've already tried with  `fileOptions.chunkedMode = false;` since it is commented...

Comment: System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile); yes it is actualti work if i use the test page i made for upload the file but when i try in cordova app dont work, says it is null.

Comment: yes i have tried fileOptions.chunkedMode = false, but same result, you dont know any web page that do same thing i am triying to do ?

Comment: Try looping and printing all the request parameters from the action method, and see what is passed to the action

Comment: apparently between parameters is not the file i try to upload however i think it is there but the struts2 do not see it because it is not in the param i will try with the test page i make to test this if i can a put the result here